# Internet Explorer: get string from an XML file using the .html()-function

Tags: jquery, xml

Good evening,

I have a problem getting my code to run on Internet Explorer.

My script has to read an XML file and store the whole formated text (with tagnames, attributes etc etc) within a string. For this procedure I'm using code, like the following

```
xmlText = $(xml).find("body").html()
```

The example shows my solution that works quite well in Chrome or Firefox. Internet Explorer has a problem with the **.html()**-function tho.

I tested the jquery **.children()**-function aswell, which works, but in my case this function is not an option because I need to check the string *xmlText* for specific expressions (elements) later.

Do you guys know some workarround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var element = $(xml).find("body").get(0);
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
xmlText = serializer.serializeToString(element);
```